# PrimeFaces filling dataTable with List<Object> inside another List<Object>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datagrid, xhtml

**UPDATE:**

I found that the issue with the dataGrid not looping through a list inside a list was an issue on the XML code side. Now the dataGrid is reading the List and looping through it creating panels based on the name. The issue now seems to be accessing certain properties in this List.

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{objList.objList2}" var="objList2" columns="1">  
    <p:panel id="obj2" header="#{objList2.name}" toggleable="true" collapsed="false"> 
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%" columnClasses="scenario-viewer-leftcolumn,scenario-viewer-rightcolumn">
                    <h:outputText value="Output Name:"  />
                    <p:inputText value="#{objList2.objType}" styleClass="textBoxStyle"/>
                    <h:outputText value="Output Bool:"  />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{objList2.boolVar}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
 </p:dataGrid>
    </p:panel>
</p:dataGrid>
```

When I try to access a variable under objList2 is gives me the error saying The class obj2 does not have a readable property 'objType'. I double checked and it does have this property/variable and it is initialized.

What makes this even more strange is if I use objList2.boolVar in place of objList2.name in the header for each panel, it displays the information fine. This proves that the property exists and is initialized. Why wouldn't this work in inputText?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ORIGINAL:**

I am working with PrimeFaces and trying to create a xhtml form for my UI. I am trying to dynamically display data from a list into a dataGrid structure. I am able to do this successfully, but I also need to display data from a list inside the first list.

For example:

I have a List under the variable objList which I use for my first dataGrid. I am able to loop through this list and create panels for each object and some other String data per object.

```
 <p:dataGrid value="#{scenarioTree.objList}" var="objList" columns="1">  
        <p:panel id="obj" header="#{objList.name}" toggleable="true" collapsed="true"> 
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%" columnClasses="scenario-viewer-leftcolumn,scenario-viewer-rightcolumn">
            <h:outputText value="text:"  />
            <p:inputText value="#{objList.variable}" styleClass="textBoxStyle"/>
            <h:outputText value="text2:"  />
            <p:inputText value="#{objList.variable2}" styleClass="textBoxStyle"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

Now I want to be able to create a second dataGrid that refers to objList2 which is inside objList1. Doing this though returns No records found in the UI even though there is a bunch of records there.

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{objList.objList2}" var="objList2" columns="1">  
    <p:panel id="obj2" header="#{objList2.name}" toggleable="true" collapsed="false"> 
        </p:panel>
 </p:dataGrid>
    </p:panel>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Is this a bug with PrimeFaces or am I not able to do this? Or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

whenever we are talking about iterating list in xhtml we have dataTable,dataGrid, etc and panelGrid also becoz dataTable and all others are child of panelGrid(we can say this becoz panelGrid is also going to form table and others as well i meant child from this way) so in this case try to iterate the inner list in panelGrid since you are using panelGrid and referring variable is list so internally jsf is going to understand like this:

```
objList.get(i).getVariable();//For the first row
```

but according to your code it is understanding like this:

```
objList.getVariable();
```

which is not at all present so it is giving issue take out panel i don't find it's use and use like this:

```
<p:panelGrid value="#{objList}" var="obj">
//Access properties inside that
</p:panelGrid>
```

you can use `<f:facet>` tag if you want something in header

Comment: <p:panelGrid> doesn't have an attribute named value. That is why I am using a dataGrid. My panelGrid is just for formatting reasons.